# По клику на ссылку фильтровать элементы по значению их атрибутов

Tags: javascript, jquery

В общем есть небольшая навигация из нескольких ссылок переход по которым я закрыл при помощи `e.preventDefault()`. Путь у ссылок - это названия категорий. Ниже располагается большой блок с множеством элементов li у которых есть атрибут `class= {название категории к которой он относится}`. Можно ли сделать так, чтобы при клике на ссылку сравнивался ее href с class'ами элементов li и те элементы у которых атрибуты не совпадали скрывались в `display:none`? Или же есть алгоритм попроще чтобы реализовать подобное действие.

```
<a href="#cat1">ссылка</a>
<a href="#cat2">ссылка</a>
<a href="#cat3">ссылка</a>
<ul>
    <li class="cat1"></li>
    <li class="cat1"></li>
    <li class="cat2"></li>
    <li class="cat2"></li>
    <li class="cat3"></li>
    <li class="cat3"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: класс может быть только один? или возможно что-то вроде: `<li class="cat1 cat-for-li"></li>`?

Comment: Один класс у каждого ли.

Comment: Или же можно вместо class использовать что-то другое, например data-category

Answer (score 0):

Примерно так

```js
$(function() {
  $('a').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var cat = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);
    $('li').hide();
    $('li.' + cat).show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#cat1">ссылка</a>
<a href="#cat2">ссылка</a>
<a href="#cat3">ссылка</a>
<ul>
  <li class="cat1">1</li>
  <li class="cat1">1</li>
  <li class="cat2">2</li>
  <li class="cat2">2</li>
  <li class="cat3">3</li>
  <li class="cat3">3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Как я понял этот вариант скрывает все элементы li, а затем откывает те, у которых в классе есть префикс сат? Проблема в том, что на деле названия категорий будут совершенно разными и вставляться автоматически в путь ссылки и в class элементу li, относящемуся к данной категории. Нужно сначала получить значение href, затем сравнить его с class'ом и если они сошлись - то открыть

Comment: @Андрей ну а здесь что не так сделано?

Comment: $('li.' + cat).show(); Это означает открыть все li у которых класс начинается с cat?

Comment: @Андрей, _Как я понял ... а затем откывает те, у которых в классе есть префикс сат_- ты понял не правильно. показываются элементы не с префиксом, а с конкретным классом. `var cat = $(this).attr('href').substr(1);` - значение переменной `cat`, это как раз имя класса. который надо показать

Comment: Этот класс будет меняться.

Comment: Вот еще одно доказательство, что переменные и классы надо понятно называть :)

Comment: @Андрей, значение берется из атрибута ссылки по которой щелкнули.

Comment: Извеняюсь, в начале дал ложную информацю. Классоа может быть несколько. Например <li class=cat1 cat2">...</li> Т.е. относиться к 2м категориям и должен открываться при нажатии на как на ссылку с href="cat1" и на ссылку с href="cat2"

Comment: @Grundy имхо, в данном конкретном случае это говорит о том, что прежде чем прогить, надо хотя бы книжку полностью изучить, любую.

Comment: А если использовать собственный атрибут data-category, то как будет выглядеть скрипт? Предыдущий вариант работать отказывается, возможно потому, что в class вставляется кирилица.